# modelsim throw error if component is not bound

Tags: modelsim

Is there a way to make modelsim throw an error instead of a warning if a component instance is not bound? Right now, it generates a warning but that is usually hard to spot in the transcript. I don't really have a need to run modelsim if it can't find the appropriate source code/signature, so it would be better in my mind to throw an error so it's obvious, then I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vsim` command line option `-warning error` promotes all warnings to errors.

While ModelSim support `-warning <msgNumber>` and `-note <msgNumber>` to promote a message (info, warning, error) to a warning or note, I can't find an option to explicitly promote a warning to an error.

On the other hand, `vcom` has such options:

```
-fatal <msgNumber>[,<msgNumber>...]
                   Report the listed messages as fatal
-error <msgNumber>[,<msgNumber>...]
                   Report the listed messages as errors
-warning <msgNumber>[,<msgNumber>...]
                   Report the listed messages as warnings
-warning error     Report all warnings as errors
-note <msgNumber>[,<msgNumber>...]
                   Report the listed message as notes
-suppress <msgNumber>[,<msgNumber>...]
                   Suppress the listed messages
```